# remove same combinations in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have a dataframe that is a edgelist for a undirected graph it looks like this:

```
    node 1 node 2 doc
0   Kn  Kn  doc5477 
1   TS  Kn  doc5477 
2   Kn  TS  doc5477 
3   TS  TS  doc5477 
4   Kn  Kn  doc10967
5   Kn  TS  doc10967
6   TS  TS  doc10967
7   TS  Kn  doc10967
```

How can I make sure that the combinations of nodes for each document only appear once. Meaning that because row 1 and 2 have are the same I only want it to appear once. Same for rows 5 and 7?

So that my dataframe looks like this:

```
    node 1 node 2 doc
0   Kn  Kn  doc5477 
1   TS  Kn  doc5477     
3   TS  TS  doc5477 
4   Kn  Kn  doc10967
5   Kn  TS  doc10967
6   TS  TS  doc10967
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select the columns on which you need a unique combination (`node1`, `node2` and `doc` in your case) then apply a sort to return a series with a list of combinations, and finally use a boolean mask with a negative [**`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to keep only the rows that represent a unique combination.

Try this:

```
out= df.loc[~df[['node 1','node 2', 'doc']].apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

  node 1 node 2        doc
0     Kn     Kn    doc5477
1     TS     Kn    doc5477
3     TS     TS    doc5477
4     Kn     Kn   doc10967
5     Kn     TS   doc10967
6     TS     TS   doc10967
```